# Want to build a search engine which modifies the URL based on clicks

Tags: php, url

So the search engine should work as following: the user clicks on given properties and those properties get added to the URL for example like this: +3000Mhz. If another similar property (example: 2133Mhz) gets clicked the +3000Mhz should be removed and the other property should be added.

The properties are clickable links like this: 1600Mhz 2133Mhz 3000Mhz

The URL will look something like this: `?query=2x4gb+DDR3+2133Mhz`

Now, as for the code I built so far:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$var = 1;
$resSP=mysql_query("select * from specifications where categoryid='15' order by specificationorder asc ");
while($rowSP=mysql_fetch_array($resSP))
{

//search for the specification
$prefix="+".$rowSP['specificationname'];
//delete the specification found
$next_link = str_replace($prefix, "", $actual_link, $var);


//if the specification is found in the URL
if (strpos($actual_link,$rowSP['specificationname']) !== false) {
//echo the current URL without the specification
    echo "<a href=\"".$next_link." \">".$rowSP['specificationname']."</a> ";
} else {
//or echo current URL without the currently applied specification and add another one   
    echo "<a href=\"".$next_link."+".$rowSP['specificationname']."\" \">".$rowSP['specificationname']."</a> ";
}
}
```

The problem I have is that the first echo works only as a way of removing a specification only if the specification of the clickable links match.
The second echo removes nothing and only adds another specification, but this way the URL will get broken (`example: ?query=2x4gb+DDR3+2133Mhz+3000Mhz`) and so brings no results.

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to accomplish. I guess I would need a code that loops through the specifications again and removes the currently applied specifications before the second echo occurs, but I'm having a difficult time with it.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To you it seems obvious, that 2133Mhz and 3000Mhz are of the same specification type, but the server do not know about this.

IMHO the cleanest way would be to use separate query fields for separate specification types: `?ramsize=2x4gb&cpufreq=3000MHz`

Of course, you need a **specificationtype** field in the database.

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]";

$resSP=mysql_query("select * from specifications where categoryid='15' order by specificationorder asc ");
while($rowSP=mysql_fetch_array($resSP)) 
{
    $query = $_GET;

    //if the specification is found in the URL
    if(array_key_exists($rowSP['specificationtype'], $query) && 
        $query[$rowSP['specificationtype']] == $rowSP['specificationname']) {
        unset($query[$rowSP['specificationtype']]);
    } else {
        $query[$rowSP['specificationtype']] = $rowSP['specificationname'];
    }

    $next_link = $link;
    if(count($query)) {
        $next_link .= '?' . http_build_query($query);
    }

    echo "<a href=\"".$next_link." \">".$rowSP['specificationname']."</a> ";
}
```